# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '3') - I need help, thanks

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to push some info into an array, but i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '3')". I have tried some different things, but nothing works.

This is the array:

```
var bil = [{
    stillingstype: "Lektor med tilleggsutdanning",
    model: "Model X",
    type: [{
        navn: "Plaid",
        pris: 1200000
      },
      {
        navn: "Long range",
        pris: 1100000
      }
    ],
    farge: [{
        farge: "Hvit",
        pris: 0
      },
      {
        farge: "Sort, sølv eller blå",
        pris: 12500
      },
      {
        farge: "Rød",
        pris: 21000
      }
    ],
    interiør: [{
        farge: "Helsort",
        pris: 0
      },
      {
        farge: "Sort og hvit",
        pris: 17500
      },
      {
        farge: "Krem",
        pris: 17500
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    stillingstype: "Lektor",
    model: "Model S",
    type: [{
        navn: "Plaid",
        pris: 1300000
      },
      {
        navn: "Long range",
        pris: 980000
      }
    ],
    farge: [{
        farge: "Hvit",
        pris: 0
      },
      {
        farge: "Sort, sølv eller blå",
        pris: 12500
      },
      {
        farge: "Rød",
        pris: 21000
      }
    ],
    interiør: [{
        farge: "Helsort",
        pris: 0
      },
      {
        farge: "Sort og hvit",
        pris: 12500
      },
      {
        farge: "Krem",
        pris: 12500
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    stillingstype: "Adjunkt",
    model: "Model 3",
    type: [{
        navn: "Performance",
        pris: 500000
      },
      {
        navn: "Long range",
        pris: 450000
      }
    ],
    farge: [{
        farge: "Hvit",
        pris: 0
      },
      {
        farge: "Sort, sølv eller blå",
        pris: 10000
      },
      {
        farge: "Rød",
        pris: 18000
      }
    ],
    interiør: [{
        farge: "Helsort",
        pris: 0
      },
      {
        farge: "Sort og hvit",
        pris: 10000
      }
    ]
  }
]
var infoPerson = [{
  fornavn: "Ola",
  etternavn: "Normann",
  stillingstype: "Lektor",
  ansattnummer: "12345",
  type: "Plaid",
  farge: "Hvit",
  interiør: "Helsort"
}];
```

And this is the pushing

```
infoPerson.push({
  fornavn: fornavn,
  etternavn: etternavn,
  stillingstype: stillingstype,
  ansattnummer: ansattnummeret,
  type: bil[index].type[i].navn,
  farge: bil[index].farge[i].farge,
  interiør: bil[index].interiør[i].farge
})
```

Does anyone know what the problem is, and how i can fix it?

Comment: What's the value of `index`? The error indicates that `bil[index]` is undefined. So `index` is out of the range of the `bil` array indexes.

Comment: The pushing code looks like it's in a loop. Show the loop. Make sure you're using `index < bil.length`, not `index <= bil.length`.

Comment: I have done this in the top: var index = document.getElementById("selectStillingstype").selectedIndex;. I also have it inside a loop, but i have only been using < and not <=

Comment: How are the indexes of the select options related to the `bil` array? Please post a [mre].

Comment: @barmar how do i post it? Im new to this so i dont understand too much